# Getting mouse coordinates every time mouse moves

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

So i have this code, however i dont get it how to set the mouse coordinates to the label every time the mouse moves ...

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        lblInfo.setText("Nada "+mouseX+mouseY);
    }

}, 1);
```

Im not even sure if the code is right but what i want it to do is to get the mouse coordinates in the label called lblInfo every time the mouse moves.

This code what does is only display it once whenever the program starts...

Comment: See [How to write a `MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Comment: How often is the run() method executed?  Add a println() to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `implements MouseMotionListener`, then add your logic inside `mouseMoved` method like:

```
public class MyClass implements MouseMotionListener {

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       System.out.println("X : " + e.getX());
       System.out.println("Y : " + e.getY());
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       //do something
    }

}
```

Read more about [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Comment: Thats the problem, i have extends MouseAdapter which inherits MouseMotionListener (if i remember correctly) , but how do i tell it to set coordinates every time the mouse moves. I can get the coordinates every time the mouse is pressed inside a JPanel for example, but not everywhere on screen. I am using mouseClicked and it works fine... But cant manage to find the right event to make it update the coordinates every time the mouse moves, and mouse Moved doesnt seem to work omg...

Comment: public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
    int mouseX = e.getX();
    int mouseY = e.getY();
    System.out.println("Test Info: "+mouseX+" "+mouseY);
    igu.lblInfo.setText("Test Info: "+mouseX+" "+mouseY);
    }

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html ,mouseMoved does not do this "Invoked when the mouse cursor has been moved onto a component but no buttons have been pushed." and i dont know why...

Comment: doh nvm im dumb xD in stead of adding addMouseMotionListener(); i used addMouseListener();

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example. You first need to implement `mousePresseded` *then* `mouseDragged`. The first to get the point of the initial press, then the `mouseDragged` will use those coordinates.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
         // Get x,y and store them
         pX = me.getX();
         pY = me.getY();
     }
});
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
         frame.setLocation(frame.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX, 
              frame.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
     }
});
```

Complete running example. It uses an undecorate frame and create a `JPanel` as the header, that you can drag to move the frame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class UndecoratedExample {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static class MainPanel extends JPanel {
        public MainPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.gray);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    static class BorderPanel extends JPanel {

        JLabel stackLabel;
        int pX, pY;

        public BorderPanel() {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                    "/resources/stackoverflow1.png"));
            stackLabel = new JLabel();
            stackLabel.setIcon(icon);

            setBackground(Color.black);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

            add(stackLabel);

            stackLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                    // Get x,y and store them
                    pX = me.getX();
                    pY = me.getY();
                }
            });
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                    frame.setLocation(frame.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX, 
                            frame.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    static class OutsidePanel extends JPanel {

        public OutsidePanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(new BorderPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.add(new OutsidePanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```